# Implementing Euler's Method in python to solve ODE

Tags: python, python-2.7, numerical-methods, numerical, differential-equations

I am working on a little science project to simulate a mechanical system with ODE (Ordinary Differential Equation).

[image: differential equations of the mechanical system]

I would like to use Euler's Method to do so, however I believe that I am doing something work, because the plot that I create of the output data isn't what it is supposed to be and I am 100% sure that the **equation** itself **is correct**. Could you look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? This code will output CSV values into console and into output.csv file.

Test:

```
class Calculus:
    def __init__(self):
        print "object created"

    @staticmethod
    def euler(f,y0,a,b,h):
        """y0 - temperatura poczatkowa, a-chwila poczatkowa czasu(warunek brzegowy) , b-chwila koncowa, h - krok"""
        t,y = a,y0
        time = [t]
        value = [y]

        while t <= b:
            print "%6.3f,%6.3f" % (t,y)

            t += h
            y += h * f(t,y, h, value)
            time.append(t)
            value.append(y)

        data = {'time' : time, 'value' : value}
        return data

class Mechanical_system:
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, momentum1, momentum2, b1, b2, N1, N2, w1, Tau, k):
        self.system_parameters = {'momentum1': momentum1, 'momentum2': momentum2,
                                               'b1': b1, 'b2' : b2, 
                                               'N1': N1, 'N2' : N2, 
                                               'w1' : w1,
                                               'Tau' : Tau,
                                               'k' : k};

    def ODE(self, time, w, h, value):
        """ODE - ordinary differential equation describing our system"""

        #first calculation will only have one value in the list, so we can't calculate delt_value = current - last
        #thus, we need to assume that if there is no penault value (index error) let penault = 0
        try:
            penault = value[len(value) -2]
        except IndexError:
            penault = 0


        momentum1 = self.system_parameters['momentum1']
        momentum2 = self.system_parameters['momentum2']
        b1 =        self.system_parameters['b1']
        b2 =        self.system_parameters['b2']
        N1 =        self.system_parameters['N1']
        N2 =        self.system_parameters['N2']
        Tau =       self.system_parameters['Tau']
        k =         self.system_parameters['k']

        dOmega = w - penault
        dt = h
        Omega = float(dOmega) / float(dt)

        return (1.0 / (momentum1 + ((N1/N2)**2)*momentum2))*(Tau - (Omega)*(b1 + ((N1/N2)**2)*b2) - w * ((N1/N2)**2)*k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        """reads values from input boxes and then calculates the value and plot value(time)"""
        momentum1 = 1
        momentum2 = 2
        b1 =        0.5
        b2 =        0.6
        N1 =        10
        N2 =        20
        a =         0
        b =         100
        h =         0.1
        w1 =        0
        Tau =       100
        k =         0.5

        system1 = Mechanical_system(momentum1, momentum2, b1, b2, N1, N2, w1, Tau, k)
        data = Calculus.euler(system1.ODE, w1, a, b, h)

        ##writing output to CSV file
        f = open('output.csv', 'w')
        for index in range(len(data['time'])):
            f.write("%s,%s\n" % (data['time'][index], data['value'][index]))

        f.close()

        del system1
        del data
```

Comment: Could you provide a test for your code? an example to run through the code.

Comment: I have updated my post so that it contains a test now. These values used in the test are "probable" for my mechanical system. They should give correct system response.

Comment: The newly added code should work, except that `N1, N2` are given as integers and the integer division `N1/N2` returns `0`. Change to `N1=10.0; N2=20.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I understand now what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Euler for mechanical systems is in general a bad idea. The easiest test case to explore this statement is the simple oscillator `x''+x=0` where you will find that the energy of the system grows rapidly.

For a general mechanical system you have an equation of motion `m*x'' = F(t,x,x')`. This gives you a vector valued system

```
def f(t,y):
    x,v = y
    return [ v; 1/m*F(t,x,v) ]
```

Notice that there is no `h` or `dt` in the system function. This is essential for ODE and their numerical treatment. The direction field that the trajectories follow do not depend on details of the numerical solution method.

So please reformulate your equation as a second order equation or a first order system in phase space.

---

I take it that your equation is meant to be

```
F(x,v) = Tau - (b1 + ((N1/N2)**2)*b2) * v -  ((N1/N2)**2)*k * x
```

with mass

```
m = momentum1 + ((N1/N2)**2)*momentum2
```

or some scaled version thereof. So some kind of spring under gravity and friction. If this is true, then you are treating the acceleration of the physical system as the velocity in the numerical implementation. Which can only give meaningless results.

---

Stripping the classes out, the second order of the system could be reflected like this:

```
def euler(f,y0,v0,a,b,h):
    t,y,v = a,y0,v0
    time = [t]
    value = [y]

    while t <= b:
        print "%6.3f,%6.3f" % (t,y)
        accel =  f(t,y,v)
        t += h
        y += h * v
        v += h*accel
        time.append(t)
        value.append(y)

    data = {'time' : time, 'value' : value}
    return data

def ODE(t,y,v,param):
    momentum1, momentum2, b1, b2, N1, N2, Tau, k = param
    mass = momentum1 + ((N1/N2)**2)*momentum2
    force = Tau - v*(b1 + ((N1/N2)**2)*b2) - y * ((N1/N2)**2)*k
    return force/mass


momentum1 = 1
momentum2 = 2
b1 =        0.5
b2 =        0.6
N1 =        10.
N2 =        20.
Tau =       100
k =         0.5    
a =         0
b =         100
h =         0.1
y0 =        0
v0 =        0

params = [momentum1, momentum2, b1, b2, N1, N2, Tau, k]
data = euler(lambda t,y,v: ODE(t,y,v,params),y0,v0,a,b,h)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough. I formulated a 2nd-order equation and then "changed" it into 1st-order equation. This equation in this example is in fact 2nd-order. In my equation Omega is a 2nd order factor, and i asume that it is equal to delta angle divided by delta time (step). I hope i explained it well enough.

Look here:http://scr.hu/4ror/f7zv8

Comment: I've added the image to your question, delete it/roll back if that was too presumptuous. -- These formulas confirm what I added to the answer. You tried to do too much at once and thus missed the order of the system.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not familiar with the structure you used to create "data" variable. I get an error "unused variable data, expected ')'. Could you tell me where should i put the ')' bracket? Also i believe that this return statement shouldn't be there :P

Comment: Code is untested, the important part was the changes inside the Euler loop and how they reflect in the ODE function. Where now `x''=f(t,x,x')` is used as scheme, where `x=omega`, `x'=v=omega'=Omega`. You could also implement the system as true order 1 system and then utilize the `numpy.ode` (or `sympy.ode`?) methods.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up matlab and python anonymous functions aka lambda expressions. No guarantee that it works now, but the call should be correct. -- Whatever you do, I don't think it wise to have any dictionary/string map lookups inside the ODE function, since it is a often called function. -- The accuracy of Euler is proportional to `T*h`, with `T=100`, `h=0.1` you get an error margin of about `10` (times the scale of the ODE function). For better accuracy you need a smaller `h` and thus inversely proportional more evaluations of the ODE function.

Comment: I edited my post, added "some answer" but I am not sure if it's correct. Could you check it and mark mistakes?